# Sending JSON Data

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, encryption

I would like to generate encrypt data and send it from `http://localhost:8888/A/B` to `http://localhost:8888/C/D` in json format.

What is the best way possible?
Users will be using only `http://localhost:8888/A/B`, so when ever a request comes in for a `http://localhost:8888/A/B` a hash key will be generated and sent to `http://localhost:8888/C/D` where the database query will happen before doing that it has to decrypt the data and check if the user is a valid one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`cURL`** to send any data anywhere. It is very flexible and configurable for any case. You can use either `POST` or `GET` methods to send data.

Answer (score 0):

you're referencing two different things.. hashing != encrytping. Hashing is one way, whereas encrytpion is two directional. use an ajax call to a codeigniter controller.